# R datatable order by columns returns unexpected subset

Tags: r, data.table

Ordering a datatable by scoped columns vs by a character vector, returns unexpected results:

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(x = rep(c('a', 'b', 'c'), 3), 
                 y = seq(1, 9, 1))
```

This is expected:

```
dt[order(x, y)]
  x y
1: a 1
2: a 4
3: a 7
4: b 2
5: b 5
6: b 8
7: c 3
8: c 6
9: c 9
```

This is not:

```
dt[order(c('x', 'y'))]
   x y
1: a 1
2: b 2
```

Is this behaviour to be expected? Can someone point documentation on why these differences happen?

Comment: You probably mean `dt[order(x, y)]`. As you wrote it, it takes the characters "x" and "y" and order them (so, basically, you're asking `dt[c(1, 2)]`)

Comment: Re documentation, in `vignette("datatable-faq")` you can see "Within the frame of a data.table, columns can be referred to as if they are variables. Therefore, we simply refer to dest and month as if they are variables."

Comment: If you want to set the order with a character vector, you can use `setorderv`. e.g. `setorderv(dt, c('x', 'y'))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`order(c("x", "y"))` simply returns the order of the character vector `c("x", "y")` which is

> ```
> [1] 1 2
> ```

So, `dt[order(c("x", "y"))]` is equivalent to

```
dt[1:2]
```

> ```
>    x y
> 1: a 1
> 2: b 2
> ```

If we interchange `x` and `y`, we get

```
dt[order(c("y", "x"))]
```

> ```
>    x y
> 1: b 2
> 2: a 1
> ```

because `order(c("y", "x"))` returns

> ```
> [1] 2 1
> ```

Comment: Indeed ordering within a datatable scope with a char vector returns the same as indexing over rows `dt[order(c('y', 'x')), x]` same as `dt[2:1, x]`. Thank you for all the answers